# Go through Pandas dataframe and remove certain chracters

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a data frame of integers as strings. Some values may have brackets in them for example "8[7]".

How would I go through each cell in the data frame and remove any brackets and number in the bracket?
For example, if there is a cell "5[6]" change the cell to "5" and do this for every cell in the df.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can apply regex to the entire df:

```
df.replace('\[(\w+)\]', '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```
s = 5[6]7
re.sub(r'\[[0-9]*\]', '', s)
```

or simply using split()

```
s.split('[')[0] + s.split('[')[1].split(']')[1]
```